# Accessibility issue in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jquery datepicker for change month and change year. While testing for accessibility, the tab is not working for the calendar, as in the calendar pops up on using tab, but after that it goes to the next field on using tab again.

Instead it should go to Previous button then Month Dropdown then year dropdown then Next button then all the dates.

Please share any solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

When the datepicker displays you'd have to get the UI element and change the tabindex properties of the child buttons accordingly.

**edit** This is actually more difficult, because you have to mess with the onfocus/onblur events as well.

The HTML5 DATE works with tabbing.

```
<input type="date" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay :) can u please tell me hw to get UI element and changing the tabindex? i tried bt unable to get any output :( ...

Comment: @user2549396 - your probably not going to be able to unfortunately. You'd likely have to override the onkeydown event for the tab key so that you keep the date picker visible then you'd have to add the tabindex to the ui-prev and ui-next classes which are the buttons on the datepicker. There's no simple drop in solution only a  lot of trial and error until you can get something workable. Making your own datepicker instead of using the jQuery UI one might be a better solution.